# Is there a difference if a variable is initialized at the point of declaration or in the constructor

Tags: typescript

If I have a variable `isEditing`, I can initialize it either at point of declaration

`isEditing:boolean = false;`

or inside a constructor

```
constructor(){
this.isEditing= false
}
```

Is there a difference between the the approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no runtime difference, no. Property initializers are relocated to the beginning of the constructor, in source-code order, just after any call to `super` if required. (JavaScript's [own property declarations](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) will work effectively the same way.)

Both this TypeScript:

```
class Example {
    public answer: number = 42;
}
```

and this TypeScript:

```
class Example {
    public answer: number;
    constructor() {
        this.answer = 42;
    }
}
```

compile to this JavaScript (when targeting ES2015+):

```
class Example {
    constructor() {
        this.answer = 42;
    }
}
```